# can't install sql-server 2008 on Windows Server 2003 standard edition SP1

Tags: sql-server-2008, installation

i can't install sql-server 2008 on Windows Server 2003 standard edition SP1

i get this error: Minimum Operation System Version Failed

thank's in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Upgrade to server 2003 SP2

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/889100

Answer (score 0):

I also had this same issue. Upgrade your Service Pack to 2 and it will work. Mine worked after that.